# Visual Studio 2015 for Unity3D Error "Incompatible Project"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, sln-file

I had UnityVS 2013 working just fine. I installed VS 2015 and uninstalled VS 2013. I installed the new VS plugin for Unity and generated the project files.

I have installed the Unity3D plugin from here:
[UnityVS Plugin 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8d26236e-4a64-4d64-8486-7df95156aba9/view/Discussions)

But now when I try to open the project I get

> Unsupported This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the
>   following projects. The project types may not be installed or this
>   version of Visual Studio may not support them.  For more information
>   on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets,
>   please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after
>   clicking OK.
>      - UnityVS.ProjectName.CSharp, "C:\~\UnityVS.ProjectName.CSharp.csproj"
>      - UnityVS.ProjectName.CSharp.Editor, "C:\~\UnityVS.ProjectName.CSharp.Editor.csproj"
>
> Non-functional changes required Visual Studio will automatically make
>   non-functional changes to the following projects in order to enable
>   them to open in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio
>   2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be
>   impacted.
>      - UnityVS.ProjectName, "C:\~\UnityVS.ProjectName.sln"

I have tried re-installing. I deleted all the solution and project files and tried re-creating them from scratch. I am running Windows 8.1.

If you have any idea why this project might not be properly working I'm all ears.

In the migration report I get this error:

> The application which this project type is based on was not found.
>   Please try this link for further information:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=E097FAD1-6243-4DAD-9C02-E9B9EFC3FFC1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok I got to work by doing the following:

1. Removed old UnityVS Folder from Unity3D
2. Delete all the csproj and sln files
   2b. *IMPORTANT* Change project settings to use MonoDevelop and NOT Visual Studio
3. Close Unity3D
4. Remove the Unity 2015 plugin
5. Reinstall Unity 2015 plugin
6. Importy Unity 2015 Unity Package
7. Click "Open In Visual Studio"

After this it worked for me

Comment: Did you set the external editor to MS VS 2015 or UnityVS.OpenFile?

Comment: I believe it set it back to MonoDevelop when I did my clean removal (it gets set back when going through the insall)

Comment: Used your checklist , but didn't have to reimport the unity package as it should be builtin. Just changed back to use vs as editor after. 
Works for me. ( man this got me spooked. Thanks for the howto )

Comment: It comes built in as of 5.2 but this was an issue for 5.0

Comment: Changing to MonoDevelop was not needed for me. Did rest of the steps and it worked.

Comment: Excellent !! I think because I installed VS after installing unity

Comment: Excellent !! I think because I installed VS after installing unity

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue with VS 2015 and unity 5.4:

1. Ensure that Visual Studio Tools for Unity (VSTU) is installed and is not visible from within "Visual Studio 2015 > Tools > Extensions and Updates..." window.
2. Then go to control panel > uninstall programs and uninstall the currently deployed VSTU (regardless of it being latest version).
3. Download and reinstall the latest VSTU from Microsoft Visual Studio site.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers including deleting and reinstalling the Tools for Unity, and deleting the projects wasn't enough to get this working for me. What made the difference was to install the Tools for Unity as Admin. I ran vstu2015.msi from an admin-elevated command prompt and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when migrating to vs2013 to vs2015

1. first download and install [Download Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Unity](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8d26236e-4a64-4d64-8486-7df95156aba9)
2. Now open your existing unity project in unity and go to the asset[menu]->Import Package->Visual Studio 2015 tools
3. Now the visual studio plugin is 2015 and you can generate new project files from Visual Studio Tools[Menu]->Generate Project files
4. Now your Unity vs solution and project files are updated to vs2015.